# Control break points between words

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive page with a text. Sometimes the breaks appear in estrange places that affect the meaning or the design. Can I control where the sentence could break?

In this simplified case for example, can I make that it breaks only at the end of the sentence? I mean if the window is bigger than 500px all the sentences will be without breaks. If the window is smaller than 500px the breaks will appear at the end of each sentence.

Here is the example to play: http://jsfiddle.net/SuJyN/

CSS:

```
#text {  
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    max-width:500px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="text">
    This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence. This is the third.
</div>
```

Comment: I reckon it's not that simple? I think the point is that it only breaks when needed?

Comment: @Artur the point is how you control the <br> only with css. That <br> cannot be always there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `white-space: pre;`

http://jsfiddle.net/SuJyN/4/

An alternative is to treat them as blocks

http://jsfiddle.net/SuJyN/8/

Comment: For more information on the possible values of the `white-space` property, see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: @John I do not see your fiddle works. Perhaps I did not explain well. The text should be continuous and only br when the window is smaller than the paragraf

Comment: @Nrc I provided another example

Comment: Yes! The second one is very good: to put sentences in a div and give a css of inline-block.

Answer (score 2):

Enter a  non-breaking space - `&nbsp;` - whenever you DON'T want the sentence to break.

Comment: This is a good solution for a specific case. But in general, when you have a lot of text this could be crazy if you want to work in all devices with so many sizes. Even in my small example I have to put a lot of &nbsp; Here is: http://jsfiddle.net/SuJyN/ Anyway, it works and is a clever solution.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#text {  
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    max-width:500px;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want control over where breaks occur **inside** words (hyphenation), you can add *soft hyphens*:

```
super&shy;cali&shy;fragilistic&shy;expiali&shy;docious
```

...or use a script like [hyphenator.js](https://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/) to do that for you.